# How to cast COM objects of different types to same class or interface?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, com, translate

There's this legacy product that it's interface is written in c++ and it's core is in VB and accessible as com objects. They want us to rewrite the interface in c# and leave the core untouched. Now I'm working on the part that consumes objects implemented in VB. These objects are actually a set of different classes with identical names and declarations that are implemented in different DLLs like this:

```
'first dll
<Microsoft.VisualBasic.ComClass(), System.Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("CoreA.clsFoo")> 
Public Class clsFoo
    Public Function DoSomething() As Byte
        'do something
    End Function
End Class

...

'second dll
<Microsoft.VisualBasic.ComClass(), System.Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("CoreB.clsFoo")> 
Public Class clsFoo
    Public Function DoSomething() As Byte
        'do something
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, in c++ side, based on an option, one of these classes will be instantiated and stored in a variable of type `CoreA.clsFoo`!

```
HRESULT hresult;
CLSID clsid;
CoreA::clsFoo* ptrFoo;

if (someCondition)
{
    hresult=CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("CoreA.clsFoo"),&clsid);
    hresult=CoCreateInstance(clsid,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,__uuidof(CoreA::clsFoo),(LPVOID *) &ptrFoo);
}
else
{
    hresult=CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("CoreB.clsFoo"),&clsid);
    hresult=CoCreateInstance(clsid,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,__uuidof(CoreB::clsFoo),(LPVOID *) &ptrFoo);
}
if( FAILED(hresult) ) 
{
    _com_issue_error(hresult);
}
```

Now I have problem with translating this piece of code in c# where all my attempts lead to some sort of invalid cast.

**What I've done so far**
First I added references to both dlls and created instance of different classes. But it was just when I tried to cast the `CoreB.clsFoo` to same `CoreA.clsFoo`, that I realized these are completely unrelated classes (yeah, dumb me ...).
I then tried to translate the C++ code above that became something like this:

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int CLSIDFromProgID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszProgID, out Guid pclsid);
[DllImport("ole32.Dll")]
static public extern uint CoCreateInstance(ref Guid clsid,
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object inner,
   uint context,
   ref Guid uuid,
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object rReturnedComObject);
static readonly uint CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER = 1;

private readonly object foo;

internal CoreA.clsFoo GetFoo()
{
    return (CoreA.clsFoo)this.foo;
}

internal CreateFoo(bool someCondition)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        int hresult = CLSIDFromProgID("CoreA.clsFoo", out Guid clsid);
        Guid uuid = typeof(CoreA.clsFoo._clsFoo).GUID;
        uint hresult2 = CoCreateInstance(ref clsid, null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ref uuid, out foo);
    }
    else
    {
        int hresult = CLSIDFromProgID("CoreB. clsFoo", out Guid clsid);
        Guid uuid = typeof(CoreB.clsFoo._clsFoo).GUID;
        uint hresult2 = CoCreateInstance(ref clsid, null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ref uuid, out foo);
    }
}
```

But this one also gets an invalid cast exception, this time from `__ComObject` to `CoreA.clsFoo`.

**The correct way to handle this**
I think the best way to fix this is changing declaration of these classes in VB. But for some reasons they want us to use the very same builds of VB dlls as the prior product. The other option is to write a new class in c# with same set of functions as `CoreX.clsFoo`s and call specific method of different instantiated objects based on `someCondition`. But I truly try to avoid this since there are tens of these dlls and the `DoSomthing()` method mentioned above actually represents 2.305e93 different methods!

So, is there a way to perform some naive type casting in C#, just like what is done in C++?

Comment: A simple `(CoreA.clsFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CoreA.clsFoo"))` (C#) should work

Comment: @SimonMourier apparently I was not clear enough, but I need something like `(CoreA.clsFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CoreB.clsFoo")`.

Comment: Then CoreA.clsFoo must be a common interface or class from which both derive

Comment: The C++ language gives you enough rope, compilers are not required to generate a diagnostic for undefined behavior.  Very dangerous, a small change to one of the interface types produces a bug that is quite hard to diagnose.  Completely illegal in COM as well, QueryInterface is a hard requirement.  This kind of UB is explicitly forbidden in C# and VB.NET, with a runtime check to enforce it.  No workaround, you need to either use two variables,  use *dynamic* or create a new interface that is implemented by both classes.  The latter is the most correct and performant way to do it.

Comment: Your VB code looks like VB.NET. not VB6. If that is the case, why do you need to use COM to wrap the VB code in C#?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs You are right, I changed the tag. But I was desperately trying to find a workaround for casting instances of different classes. As I said I can create instances with no problem just after adding reference to the assembly.

Comment: Did you try using `dynamic` as Hans suggested? At first glance that seems like the right approach to me.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs No, I didn't try it. I'm not allowed to make any changes on VB side. Finally I declared a new class in C# project that creates an instance of either of so called `CoreA.clsFoo` or `CoreB.clsFoo` classes. This new class has several methods with single switch-case expressions that call desired methods of the correct instance.

Comment: That solution makes sense. But I meant to use dynamic on the C# side...